# Html code to you put a picture on the title

Tags: html, favicon

How would I make a picture be in the title of the website using html

```
    <html>  
    <head> 

    <title src="android.jpg"> Androids apps </title>

    </head> 
    </html>
```

That did not work does anybody know how to do that

Comment: I am pretty sure title is text only. You may want a `favicon`

Answer (score 5):

I think you're referring to a [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

You can put a favicon.ico file in the root of the website or link to it in your `head`

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: I tired that it did not work is it like this <link rel="Desktop/Programing/Coding/Richards website/Title.ico" href="Title.ico" />
    <title>Androids apps</title>

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is favicon.ico

Here is a generator http://www.favicon.cc/